# get request variable return undefined in spring controller

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, get

I have a get request in angular that takes a string param

```
method: 'GET',
      url: '/urle?data='+$scope.data,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
```

consuming tha above endpoint in postman returns useful data but in springboot controller, the data variable echoes undefined

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/urle"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")  //
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseData getNData @RequestParam(value="data") String data, HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("@... inside controller");

        System.out.println("here is data " + String.valueOf(data)); //prints undefined
        if(av == null) {
            return ResponseData.successData("no data available 2");
        }
```

everything is working fine in postman but why is my spring controller not returning the data of the get parameter rather than undefined

Comment: Before firing-off the request, check what is assigned to `$scope.data`.

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for the insights @31piy

Comment: Check the Developer Console for error messages. The request could be blocked by the browser because of CORS violations.